# Why does jquery not obtain the "value" of the hidden field?

Tags: jquery

I use an ajax call to build a div and it works well but I need to return a value as well. I tried to return the HTML5 and the "val" as key/value pairs but could not get it to work so I thought I would add a hidden field but could not get that to work either. I tried async and async=false. I would appreciate it if both ways were explained (for my education).

From the ajax called program after the HTML5 has been generated.

```
    $HTML5.='<input id="mymove" type="hidden" value="'.$move.'"';
    echo"$HTML5";
```

From the calling program (myval displays "undefined")

```
    function getadverts(idprodxxx,offset,page){
      var myval;
      $.ajax({
        url : 'xml_get.php',
        async: false,
        data:{"idprodxxx":idprodxxx,
              "offset":offset,
              "page":page,
              },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            myval=$("#mymove").val();
            alert(myval);
            $('#content_sidebar').html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

I have googled this and spent yesterday afternoon and all of today trying to get this to work.

Comment: did u check the Browser Inspector >>  Network to see if the request goes thorugh? What value is alerted?

Comment: try and replace $move with a static value if it isnt already, just for debugging purposes. For the sync/async part. It is generally frown upon making AJAX as a sync call.. Hence the name (Async Javascript and XML). If you make the call sync it basically means you are waiting for the call to complete compared to async where it runs in the background. Deeper explaination here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests)

Comment: In your success function, you are trying to access `#mymove` – but that’s not even in the DOM yet, because you only append the received HTML code (in `data`) two lines further down …

Comment: And btw., I’d suggest rather then putting hidden input fields into the DOM to read a value back from that afterwards, return some kind of JSON data structure, that contains your HTML code and your extra value as different properties.